# Rest-framework ID issue on React frontend to display data in a "color yes, color no" mode

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build an API server with Django and React as frontend.

I'm having an issue with the id I'll be using to display the publications on my React page. My goal is to display a "color yes, color no" background (black, white, black, white ... for instance).

In React I have this so far:

```
{news && news.list.map((item) => {
                        
    return(

        <NewsPiece 
            key={item.id}
            title={item.title}
            active={item.id % 2 === 0 ? true : false} #when active, white, otherwise black
        />                            
    )
})}
```

This is my modal in Django.

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    subTitle = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)    
    inter = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True) #if my publication is in english or not
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

And below is my serializer:

```
class PublicationMiniSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    newsPaper = NewsPaperSerializer(many=False)
    columnist = ColumnistSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = ('title', 'id', 'created_at')
```

And this is a short example of what my DB look like:

```
------
id: 1 #display color would be black as id % 2 === 0 is false
Title: esse é o título #(this is the title in pt-br :))
inter: false

------
id: 2 #display color would be white
Title: this is the title
inter: True

------
id: 3 #display black
Title: esse é o título #(this is the title in pt-br :))
inter: False

------
id: 4 #display white
Title: this is the title
inter: True
```

If I try to display this on both types (when inter is false and true) it works fine. The id is sequential and I can make react use black and white according to my condition (id % 2 === 0 ? true : false).

But my goal is to have the option to filter publications by international parameter. So if the filter equals "inter == True" I would have this.

```
------
id: 2 #display color would be white
Title: this is the title
inter: True

------
id: 4 #display white
Title: this is the title
inter: True
```

In this scenario, I would have white and white.

**Test 1:**
I tried first to change the behave of my React component. Instead of passing the Id, I use the loop number.

```
{news && news.list.map((item, i) => {
                        
    return(

        <NewsPiece 
            key={item.id}
            title={item.title}
            active={i % 2 === 0 ? true : false} #when active, black, otherwise white
        />                            
    )
})}
```

This would work, but it is not a good way because when I change something on this component (for instance, add a new element in the beginning) it would reload everything again.

**Test 1 (the furthest I went by myself up to now):**

I changed the behave of my modal and append two fields: inter_id and national_id.

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    subTitle = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    inter = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    inter_id = models.IntegerField(null=True) 
    national_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        top = Publication.objects.order_by('-id').filter(inter=self.inter)[0]
        if self.inter:
            self.inter_id = top.inter_id + 1
        else:
            self.national_id = top.national_id + 1

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I save the Publication item, the save method is called. Then I create a "fake id" for international and for national. The id would be set according to the "inter" field (true or false). I think this part is kind of self-explanatory.

And follow my serializer.

```
class PublicationMiniSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    newsPaper = NewsPaperSerializer(many=False)
    columnist = ColumnistSerializer(many=False)
    id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = ('title', 'id', 'headLine', 'newsPaper', 'columnist', 'created_at')


    def get_id(self, obj):
        if obj.inter:
            return obj.inter_id
            
        return obj.national_id
```

In this code, I overwrote my id so it would represent my inter_id or national_id based on the condition "if inter == true". I'm glad to achieve this. This way, the "id" would be a representation of the nationa_id and international_id (and both variables would be "counting" the position on the database).

**My issue is:**
With my solution, I would have to make another query every time I add a Publication to find the last inter or national id. I didn't like this so much... I think I can do better.

**Question:**

I was wondering if there is a way to pass to the serializer the current position of the object in the serializer query.

For instance.

My query has 20 items. From 0 to 20. The first element will have the id 0 and the last, the id of 20. On the next page, 21 to 40, the first would have the id of 21...

Is there a way of doing this?
Do you guys have an even better approach?

Hope that I made myself understood.
If you have any doubts, please let me know and I try to explain in other words.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found a much easier way. I was overthinking the issue and forgot to use the most obvious way: CSS

Instead of trying to use the id to define the color of the line, I use the [even and odd options in CSS](https://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/css-table-alternating-rows.php). So it is not necessary to handle all that stuff in django-rest-framework or mix up with my react code.

This is my react element:

```
{news && news.list.map((item) => {
                        
    return(

        <NewsPiece 
            key={item.id}
            title={item.title}
            #####active={item.id % 2 === 0 ? true : false} #when active, white, otherwise black
        />                            
    )
})}
```

NewsPiece was created with styled-components

To handle odd and even, I created another element Section and wrapped NewsPiece in it. My NewsPiece element, in fact, is a "li" with the title inside.

And this is my section.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Section = styled.section`

    li:nth-child(even){
        background: black;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    li:nth-child(odd){
        background: white;

    }

`;
```

This way I can achieve what I want without the need to change even a line in my backend and frontend react code.